# Save image to windows phone 7 pictures hub

Tags: windows-phone-7, save, image

I'm trying to save a selected picture in a listbox to phone's memory but i don't understand why i'm getting an "InvalidOperationException was Unhandled" error.

```
        var filePath = "Uploads/" + fileListBox.SelectedItem;
        var fileUriSource = new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Relative);

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(filePath.ToString(), FileMode.Open))
            {
                MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
                Picture pic = mediaLibrary.SavePicture("saved" + filePath.ToString(), fileStream);
                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

I already search on the internet but i couldn't find any answer. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen to be on a phone connected to the PC by a USB cable? If so disconnect it.

Comment: Is this in the emulator, or using a real phone?

Comment: i'm using the wp7 emulator. There are diffenreces between the emulator and the phone besides performance? I mean when you're working with isolated storage, file stream...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicture.aspx):

> InvalidOperationException
>
> Exception that is thrown if SavePicture is called while the user is
>   tethered to a computer running .

This is because the library is locked when connected to Zune on the PC to avoid any issues with changing files during syncing.
If you must do this on a device while connected you can [use the WPConnect tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180729%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) instead of Zune.